# Storing/updating 11 sets of slightly different data

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently attempting to build a database in Access that can update and track changes to 11 slightly different versions of 10-page report depending on the state it relates to (state = states of America). This report is currently broken down by paragraph into 190 entries in a field (denoted as Policy Language), and I am trying to find the best way to store this behemoth. There would be about 2100 records in a single field I put them all into state, but I think that would be pretty inefficient.

I am applying certain criteria to each paragraph, and will use that to create an updated report for each state. They are number-coded.

So basically, what would be the best way to store all of this information to fit my needs? I've also thought of 11 different tables for the states, but that too seemed like a relationship and integrity nightmare.

[image]

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. Can you show the report and issue you are having? Also, *StateRules* should not be a wide table but long with a State indicator field adjacent to value field.

Comment: The issue was in the design of the database itself. I figured out the design but with my limited knowledge of databases I was trying to connect a record directly to a field which (I think?) is impossible the way i was doing it.